# Running javascript through a proxy with selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, proxy, browsermob-proxy

I have Selenium 2 in Java running through BrowserMobProxyServer (on firefox) since I need to capture certain network events as I navigate a form. I have a javascript command that I can call via JavascriptExecutor with .executeScript("script.test") but this does not work if the proxy is on. It works fine with the proxy off - is there a way to have this work with the proxy on or is javascript injection not possible through a proxy?

Here is my driver creation with the proxy.

```
             server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
             server.start();
             int port = server.getPort();
             String proxy_address = "127.0.0.1:"+port+"";
             org.openqa.selenium.Proxy selenium_proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
             selenium_proxy.setHttpProxy(proxy_address)
                     .setFtpProxy(proxy_address)
                     .setSslProxy(proxy_address);
             Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(server);

             DesiredCapabilities seleniumCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
             seleniumCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,selenium_proxy);
             seleniumCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS,true);
             seleniumCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
             driver = new FirefoxDriver(seleniumCapabilities);
```

My javascript test looks like the below.

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("script.test"); //Expect to have the form reach the result page
    Assert that an element on the result page is present
```

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: I've just provided some code on how I set up my proxy and what I use to run the test. There's no other trace that I can really provide since the expected result of "script.test" is to reach the results page of the form which I can clearly see is working with the proxy turned off and not working with the proxy on.